# English term or phrase for the German "spötteln"

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

The German term "spötteln" means -perhaps- a light version of "spotten" for which LEO.org gives english words like "to jeer", [edited] "jibe" [/edited], "scoff" or "taunt".
But "spötteln" has something much lighter than "spott", for me it has - without really bad-will- a lightly amused state of mind in the speaker ... difficult to say...

Q: What would be an English approximation to this?

---

Example sentences:

> "Vater hatte stets die Angewohnheit, über die Freundinnen seiner Söhne zu spötteln"

or

> "Sogar in Zeiten, in denen es ihr wirtschaftlich nicht gut ging, brachte Oma es fertig, stets eine leicht spöttelnde Art im Gespräch über die alltäglichsten Dinge aufrechtzuerhalten".

The proposal from the AI at [DeepL translator](https://www.deepL.com/translate) gave the following translation of the above examples:

> *"Father always had a habit of mocking his sons' girlfriends."*

> *"Even in times when she was not doing well economically, Grandma always managed to maintain a slightly mocking manner in conversation about the most mundane things."*

My take: "mocking" seems to be too sharp here (in my understanding); the "spötteln"-behaviour in interpersonal communication would not use really snide jokes (again: in my understanding) .

Comment: Probably no comparable phrase. But still you owe us a sentence.

Comment: What is "scibe"? It's not in the dictionaries I've just looked in. Is that meant to be "jibe"?

Comment: @psmears - you might be right. I'll see in the afternoon and in case I'll correct it. (If you like you may do it as well)

Comment: A clarification about the German meaning: does *“Vater hatte stets die Angewohnheit, über die Freundinnen seiner Söhne zu spötteln”* mean that father is saying teasing things *to* the girlfriends themselves, or just saying teasing things *about* them but not necessarily *to* them?

Comment: @PLL - didn't think much about this specific point; but my phantasies with this expression go in the direction of saying ironic/... things - in some easy communication, say at the daily dinner of the family, but in absence of the girlfriends.

Comment: For me you describe "necken". The right answer for necken would probably be tease. However, spötteln may be quite malicious. Its more or less "light" or "hidden mockery": "leicht spöttische Bemerkungen machen, auf versteckte Weise spotten" with "spott" being german for "mockery".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> **tease** [<sup><sub>(dictionary.com)</sub></sup>](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tease)
> to irritate or provoke with persistent petty distractions, **trifling jests**, or other annoyances, **often in a playful way**
> *If your little sister is teasing you about your boyfriend and following you around making kissy faces, it’s because she’s jealous and wants your attention.*

Comment: Very nice cite, ideed! A fine difference might be that the "spötteln" is not so *active* as the little sister; I know a type of "spötteln" which is more a reflexion of a "being amused in oneself" and only share to the out as otherwise daily communication goes on. (But I fear this "making precise" begins to go astray now... )

Comment: The important point is that - as you already know - verbs like "to jeer", "scoff" or "taunt" (I don't recognize your "scibe") can often imply making fun of someone ***with malice***, but ***teasing*** almost always implies ***playfully / affectionately***.

Comment: And it can be verbal; it doesn't have to involve actions.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: The quote in this answer describes a particularly active kind of teasing, but teasing isn’t necessarily so active.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: As PLL points out, you shouldn't assume that just because an answer here cites *one* usage example, that precisely illustrates the only scope of the term under consideration. I also suggest you consider the implications of [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trifled+with+him%2Cteased+him&year_start=1750&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10), which clearly shows that although your preferred answer here *(**trifled with him**)* was more common than ***teased him*** 250 years ago, it's virtually unknown today. That's why my answer gets the votes!

Comment: @ Fumblefingers - I see now (and sense it) that your idea is likely the best one. Changed the "accepted" mark.

Comment: Tease is a good translation of the German "necken", but not really a good translation of spötteln:  "light or hidden mockery": leicht spöttische Bemerkungen machen, auf versteckte Weise spotten https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spoetteln.

Answer (score 6):

> "spötteln" Q: What would be an English approximation to this?

"Father always had a habit of *making light-hearted remarks about* his sons' girlfriends"

"Even in times when she was not doing well economically, Grandma always managed to maintain a *light-hearted* approach to conversation about the most mundane things."

OED

> **light-hearted**
>
> 1.b. Characterized by cheerfulness or easiness; amusing, entertaining.
>
> 2007   Daily Tel. 9 July 17/5   *A light-hearted speech in which he talked about his own problems with drink.*

And from Google Books:

> "Play from Birth to Twelve: Contexts, Perspectives, and Meanings"
> Doris Pronin Fromberg, ‎Doris Bergen · 2015 PAGE 138
>
> *His or her attitude can visibly shift from a lighthearted, “What if I do this?” attitude to a “Why won't it do that?” attitude. This shift from “I” to “it” is the death knell for constructive play (Forman & Hill, 1984).*

**light-hearted** also has the nuance of "not taking the subject too seriously".

> 1919   H. F. P. Battersby Edge of Doom xxx. 259   *The merry young gunner made some light-hearted remark on their morale, and was startled and almost shocked by the curse that came from Chaytor on the ways of war.*

Comment: Greaybeard - thanks. Good idea - and many thanks for the giving of the three references!  I just was to "accept" that but saw then the answer of Joachim, which pleases me more because it seems to be more precise to my intent. (Please see my comment at his answer)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I would caution you against “trifle”. It is a very old-fashioned verb; OED: **To toy, play (with a material object); to handle or finger a thing idly; to fiddle, fidget with.** -- *He trifles quite ferociously with his dessert-knife.* It is now only used intransitively (usually, “with + NP") where the NP is a material object. The verb cannot be used in either of your sentences: *"Father had a habit of trifling his sons' girlfriends" -- " Grandma managed to trifle a slightly mocking manner”* are both incomprehensible.

Comment: Thanks Greybeard! I'll look at it, have to go out for the afternoon...

Comment: Greybeard - back home. Well, your comment makes a strong point, indeed. Perhaps there is nothing near enough (for my sense) to this "spötteln", I think I'd give up and leave this aside ... Really thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

I would have suggested both 'mocking' and 'taunting', as well, but how about 'trifle'?

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/trifle) defines it as:

> to deal lightly or without due seriousness or respect

Etymologically, 'trifle' is related to 'idle talk', 'deceit', and, again, 'mocking', but (especially in comparison to the other synonyms) I think the *idleness* has emphasis here—it is also defined as "*to act or talk in an idle or frivolous way*"—and this lack of complete interest, concern, and (therefore) contempt, seems to be at the core of 'spötteln'.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the best approximation, many thanks! I feel it is exactly what I wanted express myself. Against the  "lighthearted" without further attributes it doesn't completely loose the relation to its (unfriendly) root of "spott"/"spotten","verspotten" and this is also essentially to my intent with this word "spötteln".

Comment: Can you explain how you would use "trifle" in the two examples given?

Comment: @Greybeard Good question. "*Father always had a habit of trifling with his sons' girlfriends*" would be the correct use, but it indeed (as in: I think that was your point) sounds off. Is it not common to use it in this way? It also seems to be used more often with abstractions, like 'feelings' or 'love'. "*Father always had a habit of trifling with his son's feelings*" sounds a lot more usual.

Comment: *"Father always had a habit of trifling with his sons' girlfriends"* **Ha!** That would mean "Father always had a habit of flirting and behaving in an amorous manner, especially touching them, with his sons' girlfriends"

Comment: @Greybeard Hmm, not entirely what the OP was looking for, methinks :)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: I really think this is *not* such a good approximation to the meaning you describe.  Some of its connotations are apt, but others are quite misleading (as Greybeard’s comment notes); besides that, it’s much less commonly used with this meaning than e.g. *tease* and other options.

Answer (score -1):

To be put on the "spot" so to speak?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).